# Revert merge without rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, revert, git-revert

I realized that a branch was merged to my master branch which shouldn't - commit is already pushed. The branch wasn't rebased - it means i don't see a one "merge commit" - the commits from the branch are in master branch now and i can't tell which commits come from merging and which were previously there.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is there a commit labeled "merge <branch name>"? (Even if the actual merged-in changes are spread out over multiple earlier commits.)

Comment: no, i only found out by chance that something was merged, there are just the commits from the branch

Answer (score 1):

Looks exactly like someone had rebased your branch on top of the current master and then fast-forwarded master to the head of your branch. Or, it could be a series of cherry-picks. The simplest thing is to revert the commits from the master branch one-by-one.

**Beware:** if you ever merge master branch with the reverted commits into your branch the commits in your branch will be also reverted.

P.S. Have a look here for revert ideas: [Rolling back in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218023/1065190)